# Using same AlertDialog box multiple times with one variable change

Tags: android, function, methods, android-alertdialog

In my application i want to use a `AlertDialog` boxes in several places. I can to this by using the code everywhere i want the `AlertDialog` box. But it seems like a waste because it's the same code with only one change. How can i use the same code for `AlertDialog` box by changing the variable?

This is my code for `AlertDialog` Box

```
private void showInternetConenctionAlert(String alert, String title) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setMessage(alert);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(topten.getFile()));
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    finish();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Here `onClick` for positive `Button` i've used

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(topten.getFile()));
                                    activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Here only thing that should be changed for me to use in other places is this.

```
topten.getFile()
```

What's the approach i should take to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost have done it yourself, just add another parameter to `showInternetConenctionAlert` function, e.g. `String uriString`, and replace the `topten.getFile()` with `uriString`.

```
private void showInternetConenctionAlert(String alert, String title, final String uriString) {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialog.setMessage(alert);
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriString));
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("No",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    finish();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a separate class  by extending DialogFragment and creating a AlertDialog in the onCreateDialog() callback method.
2. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor for example
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
   whereever you need the alert dialog box.

Check out this link, It may solve your question exactly
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html